# Adding object variable to array

Tags: java, object

I want to insert name variable of these objects to studentarray with addStudent() method.I used get method but it gives me error.Where is my mistake?Here's what i tried:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int grade;
    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name=name;
        this.grade=grade;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "name:"+this.name+"grade:"+this.grade;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Course {
    Student[]studentArray=new Student[3];

    public Course() {}

    public void addStudent(Student s) {
        for (int i=0;i<studentArray.length;i++) {
            if (studentArray[i] == null) {
                studentArray[i] =s.getName();
                break;                       
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to store a String in an array of Student objects. To add the Student to the array you can do something like this: studentArray[i] = s;

Answer (score 1):

1.You cannot have two public classes in one file.
2. You cannot convert String to Student object.
3. When you did `Student[]studentArray=new Student[3]`, you are not creating objects but 3 references.It is as same as doing `Student studentArray` three times where `studentArray` is just a reference.
4.`studentArray[i].getName();` is the right way to call a method using array of objects.

```
public class Student {
String name;
int grade;
public Student(String name, int grade) {
    this.name=name;
    this.grade=grade;
}
Student(){

}
public String toString() {
    return "name:"+this.name+"grade:"+this.grade;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}

 class Course {

 public static void main(String [] args) {
 Student[]studentArray=new Student[3];
 for( int i =0; i < studentArray.length; i++ ) {
    studentArray[i] = new Student();
  }

 for (int i=0;i<studentArray.length;i++) {
        if (studentArray[i] == null) {
            studentArray[i].getName();
            break;                       
        }
    }       
} 
}
```

Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.I will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
studentArray[i] = s;
```

Instead of:

```
studentArray[i] = s.getName();
```

Because your array stores Student type values, not their names (String class instances)

Or you can change your array type to String:

```
String[] studentArray = new String[3];
```

Instead of:

```
Student[] studentArray = new Student[3];
```

Comment: When i try this,it returns all variables of the object but i want to insrt only names.

Comment: then you should change array type to String

Comment: Change your array declaration to below :
    String[] studentArray=new String[3]

Comment: I tried that you said but i must add somethings as objects to array and it must fill it names of the objects.

Comment: didn't get you. You want to store only Student object but you want only names to be stored ? if yes, That's weird. because if you only need names then why do you need to store the Student object ?

Answer (score 0):

Your array type is Student and you are trying to store a String, name of the student that is why it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is occurring at this line

```
studentArray[i] =s.getName();
```

because you're trying to assigning data of type String to a variable of type Student. You can fix this by simplying assigning the student object in the parameter to the empty index in `studentArray`. Here is what it should like,

```
 public void addStudent(Student s) {
        for (int i=0;i<studentArray.length;i++) {
            if (studentArray[i] == null) {
                studentArray[i] = s
                break;                       
            }
        }       
 }
```